# relative velocities

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, relative-motion

If two objects are moving relative to the horizontal and you have the real angle between the horizontal and the direction of travel of one object, how does this real angle differ from the angle observed by the other object.

Comment: What do you mean by angle observed by the other object?

Comment: imagine it's a 2d problem, one object(A) is moving horizontal and the other object(B) is moving diagonally down in the same direction at a certain angle to the horizontal towards A. Because A is moving there is a relative velocity between them but is there also a relative angle observed by A between the horizontal and B?

Comment: I would call this a "vocabulary nit" except that it is too important to be a nit. ***There is no "real angle".*** There is only the angle in one frame of reference and the angle in another frame of reference. If you mean to ask about the angle as measured by a observer at rest with respect to the Earth (often called the lab frame), then do that.

Comment: What difficulty are you having with this question? Are you asking for someone to show you how to do a calculation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the angle between two objects change relative velocity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/208168)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the objects are A and B. Their velocities in the ground frame of reference are shown in blue in the diagram below.

The velocity of A relative to B is shown by the red line. It is found by subtracting the velocity of B from that of A. Relative to an observer on the ground A is moving at an angle $\alpha$ to the horizontal. Relative to B, A is moving at an angle of $\beta$ to the horizontal.

The angles $\alpha,\beta$ can be found from the vectors $\vec{V_A}, \vec{V_B}$ using geometry.

[image]